# POST value in PHP when submitting onChange Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I'm trying to submit an image file using javascript onChange, the thing is I don't know the value of the submitted POST form, and how can I set a custom POST value. Here is a simple example:
HTML:

```
<form id="form" action="upload.php" method="post">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="image">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("file").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
```

So after I submit the form I can only get the value `$_POST['image']`. Usually when receiving POST I check for the value of the submit button which I create uniquely for each form such as, updateform, updateclient. Now I want to do the same by creating custom messages, one page will send 'uploadclientimage' the other will say 'uploadshopimage' and so on. This way the upload.php file can process the status to decide what to do next.

In upload.php I want to do like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['uploadclientimage']))
    {//Save in client uploads folder and update client info}
else if(isset($_POST['uploadshopimage']))
    {//Save in shops uploads folder and update shop info}
else header("Location: login.php");
```

using submit button does that easily `<input type="submit" name="uploadclientimage">`

How can I do something like that with onChange form submit???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a hidden field in the form. For example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="uploadclientimage" value="">
```

Comment: It looks like the only way to do it ... Thank you